# Setting Python script tool parameter type so that parameter accepts feature class or layer as input?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters

I would like a few of my parameters in my script tool to be able to accept either a feature class or feature layer as input.  However, I have not been able to figure out a proper parameter type to allow this.  Can anyone help me out on this seemingly simple question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Feature Layer**. FL will accept both layer and featureclass when you're in the app.